# Javascript code document.write

Tags: javascript

I'm having a little trouble, the only line that writes the text is  document.write("The room is"+ walls +"square feet"+ BR);  after i enter the doors and windows into the prompt nothing else shows up am i doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var BR = "<br />";
var galPaint = 100;
var galNeeded; 
var length;
var width;
length = prompt("enter legnth of room  in inches");
width = prompt("enter width of room in inches");
var perimeter = (Number(length)+Number(width))*2;
var walls = (perimeter*96)/Math.pow(12,2);
document.write("The room is"+ walls +"square feet"+ BR);
var doors;
var windows; 
doors = prompt("Enter Number of doors");
windows = prompt("enter number of windows");
var sqfWindow = (Number(doors)*14);
var sqftDoor = (Number(windows)*20);
var totalSqft = (walls-(sqftWindow + sqftDoor));
galNeeded = (totalSqft/galpaint);
document.write("You need" + galNeeded + "gallons of paint" + BR);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: note: `document.write` is never (hardly ever) good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go, https://jsfiddle.net/4omvboz8/1/

You had a few typos in your code :), fixed those and cleaned up the variables, etc.. added a div element and wrote to that instead of document.write..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="textArea"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var galPaint = 100, galNeeded, length, width, 
perimeter, walls, doors, windows, sqfWindow, 
sqftDoor, totalSqft, 
textarea = document.getElementById("textArea");

length = prompt("enter legnth of room  in inches");
width = prompt("enter width of room in inches");

perimeter = (Number(length)+Number(width))*2;
walls = (perimeter*96)/Math.pow(12,2);

textarea.innerHTML += "The room is "+ walls +" square feet <br />";

doors = prompt("Enter Number of doors");
windows = prompt("Enter number of windows");

sqftDoor = (Number(doors)*14);
sqftWindow = (Number(windows)*20);
totalSqft = (walls-(sqftWindow + sqftDoor));
galNeeded = (totalSqft/galPaint);

textarea.innerHTML += "You need " + galNeeded + " gallons of paint <br />"; 
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped